# Few questions about RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So far I was using ListView in my apps. It was simple to implement. Now I decided to use RecyclerView for my next project. This app is supposed to retrieve some data as JSON from a web service. This data included a title, some text and an image.

So here are my questions:

- Is there any way to lazy load images in RecyclerView?
- Does RecyclerView reduce memory usage when data set is large?
- Is it possible to use `SwipeRefreshLayout` (Pull to refresh) with RecyclerView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android is an evolving platform. Recently 5.0 (Lollipop) version of Android was released, along with the `official RecyclerView support v7 library`. As per the official documentation [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) is a major enhancement over ListView .

- Is there any way to lazy load images in RecyclerView? **Yes**
- Does RecyclerView reduce memory usage when data set is large? **I think Yes**
- Is it possible to use `SwipeRefreshLayout` (Pull to refresh) with RecyclerView? **Yes**

Please check **[Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)** . It has memory cache, disk cache and it loads your images asynchronously so doesn't **DESTROY** the Memory. You can set default image and/or failed to fetch image etc. It can sample down your image to decrease the memory footprint of the bitmap.

**RecyclerView** is indeed a powerful view than **ListView** .

**[SwipeRefreshLayout](http://sapandiwakar.in/pull-to-refresh-for-android-recyclerview-or-any-other-vertically-scrolling-view/)**